# Is the Canon XL1 lens (1999) compatible with any of the new prosumer 1080 HD Canon bodies?

Tags: canon

Looking at  5D, 7D, EOS body or anything Canon that shoots HD video for less than $1,500... anything that is at least 18mpx and want to use that old xl1 lens from my old XL1 SD miniDV cam... can i use it, or do i need to buy a new lens setup to shoot 1080p HD?

Comment: Dossible publicate; https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/56363/is-it-possible-to-use-the-lenses-from-a-canon-xl1-on-a-modern-dslr     TL;DR: You could use it on some DSLM but not on a DSLR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No the XL 1 lens will not work with any Canon DSLR as it projects a much smaller image circle and is designed to sit much closer to the sensor than SLR lenses, which have to accommodate a mirror.

The good news is that full HD video is only 2 megapixels, so any EF or EFs mount lens will provide more than enough resolution for anybody's HD needs.

Comment: How do we know it won't work there is not a adapter or a mount out there to try so I think someone in the Canon Corporation needs to make one so we can test it out that's just my suggestion I have a canon video lens 16x zoom and I have a newer camera a canon eos rebel t3 make a mount or adaptor to fit both and we will see if it works thanks

Comment: @Crystal Kelly The lens registration of the XL1 mount is too short to work on an EF mount DSLR. An adapter would need expensive added optics in it. You could improvise an adapter for MFT mount cameras (eg a Panasonic GH5), https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/98250/is-it-possible-to-adapt-a-canon-xl-system-lens-to-a-mirrorless-body?rq=1